# How to "if not an integer , alert and repeat prompt" ? the same with isNAN

Tags: javascript, alert, prompt, fizzbuzz

i m struggling with this.
How to "if not an integer , alert and repeat prompt" ?
I have the alert working , but i cant make it to prompt again.

The same with isNAN which is not working at all!

Thank you

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fizzBuzz = function () {
        var userNum = prompt('Enter a number!');
        var convertNum = +userNum;
        for (var i = 1; i <= convertNum; i++) {
            if (i % 15 === 0) {
                $('ul').append('<li>' + "fizzbuzz" + '</li>');
            } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
                $('ul').append('<li>' + "fizz" + '</li>');
            } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
                $('ul').append('<li>' + "buzz" + '</li>');
            } else if (isNaN(userNum)) {
                alert("Input is not a number");
            } else if (convertNum % 1 !== 0) {
                alert('Please enter a whole number');
                return false;         
            } else {
                $('ul').append('<li>' + i + '</li>');
            }
        }
    };
    fizzBuzz();
});
```

Comment: are you getting the "Input is not a number" alert?

Comment: You should check if it is a number before iterate it in the *for* loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the logical order of your if statements and loop is incorrect for what you are trying to achieve.  you want to first check if this number is a number, then you want to check if tis a whole number, then you want to enter the for loop if it passes those 2 requirements.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fizzBuzz = function () {
        var userNum = prompt('Enter a number!');
        var convertNum = +userNum;
        if(isNaN(userNum)){
            alert("Input is not a number");
            fizzBuzz();
        }
        else if (convertNum % 1 !== 0) {
            alert('Please enter a whole number');
            fizzBuzz();
        }
        else {
            for (var i = 1; i <= convertNum; i++) {
                if (i % 15 === 0) {
                    $('ul').append('<li>' + "fizzbuzz" + '</li>');
                } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
                    $('ul').append('<li>' + "fizz" + '</li>');
                } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
                    $('ul').append('<li>' + "buzz" + '</li>');
                } else {
                    $('ul').append('<li>' + i + '</li>');
                }
            }
        }

    };
    fizzBuzz();
});
```

Comment: Thank you indubitablee! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Simply have a loop which will only exit once the user has entered a value which is numeric, for example

```
var userNum = null;
while(userNum == null || isNaN(userNum)){
    userNum = prompt('Enter a number!');
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/7x8vjm3b/ (try entering a letter rather than a number)

You could also make this a post-loop check and add an extra message in for the user

```
do{
    userNum = prompt('Enter a number!');
    if(isNaN(userNum)){
        alert("You entered '" + userNum + "'. This is invalid - you must enter a number");   
    }
}while(isNaN(userNum));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
var fizzBuzz = function () {
        var userNum = prompt('Enter a number!');
        var convertNum = +userNum;
        if(isNaN(userNum)){
            console.log('not a number');
            fizzBuzz()
        }else{
            doSomethingElse()
        }

};
fizzBuzz();
```